# PostgreSQL sql command error column 'does not exist'

Tags: insert

```
dxdb=> \d dxtest_loadprofiletosale
                            Table "public.dxtest_loadprofiletosale"
   Column    |   Type   |                               Modifiers                               
-------------+----------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------
 id          | integer  | not null default nextval('dxtest_loadprofiletosale_id_seq'::regclass)
 TransDate   | date     | 
 IssueDate   | date     | 
 CustomerNum | smallint | not null
Indexes:
    "dxtest_loadprofiletosale_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)

dxdb=> INSERT INTO dxtest_loadprofiletosale(id, TransDate, IssueDate, CustomerNum) VALUES(1, '2015-03-04','2015-01-01',01);
ERROR:  column "transdate" of relation "dxtest_loadprofiletosale" does not exist
LINE 1: INSERT INTO dxtest_loadprofiletosale(id, TransDate, IssueDat...
```

excuse me,I already has the column "transdate", why it said does not exist?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your column is called `"TransDate"` not `transdate`. You created your table using double quotes for the column names, which makes them case sensitive and you must use double quotes **all** the time:

```
INSERT INTO dxtest_loadprofiletosale
  (id, "TransDate", "IssueDate", "CustomerNum") 
VALUES
  (1, '2015-03-04','2015-01-01',01);
```

More details about SQL identifiers are in the manual:
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS

In general it is better to **never** use double quotes - it will give you a lot less trouble in the long run.

Comment: thank you very much,then I try :INSERT INTO dxtest_loadprofiletosale(id, "TransDate", "IssueDate", "CustomerNum") VALUES(1, '2015-03-04','2015-01-01',01);
it works!